# How to use $all in MongoRepository

Tags: arrays, mongorepository

I have the following query coded which returns the correct results I wanted.  I also have a BookRepository class that extends MongoRepository.  My question is, how to turn this query to be used in BookRepository class?  I tried bookRepository.findByPublishedIsTrueAndTagsLike(selectedTags) but it's not what $all does.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("published").is(true));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("tags").all(selectedTags));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Book.class);
```

Note: selectedTags is an array list of string.